# OpenCV installation in Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu-9.04, opencv

I wish to install OpenCV in Ubuntu 9.04, I used this [installation guide](http://mohittaneja88.blogspot.com/2010/02/opencv-20-with-ubuntu-904.html), but nothing seems to work !

Is there anyone who has installed OpenCV in Ubuntu 9.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

open up synaptic package manager. (type in password if needed)

type in opencv in the search box:

> check(mark for installation) the following :
>
> everything except :
> "harpia" and "python-opencv".
>
> *opencv-doc* is optional.
>
> *python-opencv* is needed for the python interface of opencv

please note that this is **opencv version 1** not version 2.

Answer (score -1):

`sudo apt-get install python-opencv`
`python`
`>>> from opencv import cv`
`>>> from opencv import highgui`

If that doesn't work, try checking the /usr/lib/python-support/python-opencv/python2.6 folder to make sure the package installed correctly.

Comment: Who said python?